# How to fix error 'AttributeError: module 'board' has no attribute 'D5'

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, raspberry-pi, lora

I'm using a Docker container inside a Raspberry Pi. Upon accessing the container I want to run a script that I have prepared to read a humidity and temperature sensor. I already installed the `adafruit-blinka` libraries to be able to use the board function; however, when I run the Python file, I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ZDM1YTg4/lab.py", line 16, in <module>
    CS = DigitalInOut(board.D5)
                      ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'board' has no attribute 'D5'
```

The part of the code that is failing is this:

```
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction
import board
import busio
import adafruit_rfm9x
import time
import sys


FREQUENCY = 433.0  

CS = DigitalInOut(board.D5)  
RESET = DigitalInOut(board.D22) 
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, MOSI=board.D10, MISO=board.D9)
rfm9x = adafruit_rfm9x.RFM9x(spi, CS, RESET, 433.0)
rfm9x.irq = DigitalInOut(board.D2)
```

I already tried running the script file directly on the Raspberry Pi (outside the Docker container) and it works correctly, with the same configuration and libraries

Also tried:

```
sudo pip3 install --force-reinstall adafruit-blinka
```

Comment: What does `dir(board)` return? Have you looked [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-to-circuitpython/the-board-module)?

Comment: `YjIwMjUy@0cf10b50ee0f:~$ python dir.py
['CE0', 'CE1', 'D0', 'D1', 'D10', 'D11', 'D12', 'D13', 'D14', 'D15', 'D16', 'D17', 'D18', 'D19', 'D2', 'D20', 'D21', 'D22', 'D23', 'D24', 'D25', 'D26', 'D27', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'D8', 'D9', 'I2C', 'MISO', 'MISO_1', 'MOSI', 'MOSI_1', 'RX', 'RXD', 'SCK', 'SCK_1', 'SCL', 'SCLK', 'SCLK_1', 'SDA', 'SPI', 'TX', 'TXD', '__blinka__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__repo__', '__spec__', '__version__', 'ap_board', 'board_id', 'detector', 'pin', 'sys']`

Comment: I asked what`dir(board)` returns, not what `python dir.py` returns. I recommend that you include the output of `dir(board)` in your post.

Comment: sorry, I showed a file that I created that printed the contents of dir(board), I already ran dir(board) and this is what it returns.


`>>> dir(board)
['BaseDimension', 'Board', 'Dimension', 'Empty', 'Image', 'InfiniteDimension', 'Infinity', '_Empty', '_InfiniteDimension', '_Infinity', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_centred_coord', 'cornerposts', 'functools', 'imagefile_sprite', 'io', 'itertools', 'long', 'os', 'sys', 'text_sprite']
>>>`
It's strange that none of the DX pins are showing, any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you explicitly installed `board` module.

You **do NOT** have to install board module explicitly. This `board` module is different from what you need for CircuitPython.

You just need to install `adafruit-blinka`, `board` is already present in `adafruit-blinka`.

**Uninstall `board` module**

Related question on git : https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_NeoPixel/issues/55

https://pypi.org/project/Adafruit-Blinka/

[image]